# What it really is @client.event? discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord, discord.py

A few days ago I became interested in programming discord bots a bit. In the syntax of these programs I noticed a lot of unintelligible issues that I can not find an answer to. 
That's why I am asking you for help in understanding them.

All questions are based on this code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

botToken = '***'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready!')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    if message.content =='Hello':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Welcome again {}!'.format(author))


client.run(botToken)
```

What is @client.event? I found that is a event handler, but how is it worki? Why is it needed to run program? Is it somehow connected to a asyncio?

Comment: Have you heard of _decorators_ or is your question more specific than that?

Comment: I have not heard about them, i should point out that I am a novice programmer.

Comment: Then you have a starting point for your research now :)

Comment: Thanks you so much, i have already found something about these decorators, let's study now. Thanks again. :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When a `Client` receives an event from Discord, It works out what that event is and generates, or locates, the objects that were sent by the event, such as a `discord.Message` for any MESSAGE_RECEIVE events, or a `discord.Reaction` for REACTION_ADD etc.
The client then sends the objects into the method that handles those events, but you first need to tell the client what those methods are. This is where the event decorators come in.

---

Decorators are, in essence, functions that take other functions as arguments. The most common one you'll see is `@property`. This says that the function you define should be passed into the `property()` function

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self._name
```

is the same as

```
def name(self):
    return self._name

name = property(name)
```

This may be a bit confusing to wrap your head around, but this is how discord.py handles its events.

---

When you use the `@client.event` decorator on your `on_message`, what you are actually doing is saying `on_message = client.event(on_message)`

The internal code of discord.py for on_event is [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/client.py#L846)

```
def event(self, coro):
    # Validation we don't need to worry about
    setattr(self, coro.__name__, coro)
    return coro
```

Which means that it takes the function as its parameter, and sets a new attribute on the client itself. For our `on_message` example, we pass our `on_message` function into `client.event()` and it makes the client define a new `client.on_message` method that is the same method as our `on_message`.

Note: `func.__name__` returns the name of that function. `on_message.__name__` will return `"on_message"`.
`setattr(obj, name, value)` sets an attribute on an object, so `setattr(self, "foo", 100)` means that `self.foo` will be 100.

Now that the client knows our `on_message`, when it receives an event saying that a message was sent, it creates the `discord.Message` object and passes that into `client.on_message`, which as we already established, is the same as our own `on_message`

If you wanted, you could even just skip the decorator and do this after your function, but it is less elegant than a decorator is:

```
on_message = client.event(on_message)
```